# How to add a Custom List to website using Powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint-server

I am creating a custom list via powershell. After the creation I have to open IE go to a page and add the list manually. Is there a script that will add a list into a page?

Comment: Can you show your powershell script?

Comment: how will it help?